# Populate dictionary from list in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following code that works fine and I was wondering how to implement the same logic using list comprehension.

```
def get_features(document, feature_space):
    features = {}
    for w in feature_space:
        features[w] = (w in document)
    return features
```

Also am I going to get any improvements in performance by using a list comprehension?

The thing is that both `feature_space` and `document` are relatively big and many iterations will run.

**Edit**: Sorry for not making it clear at first, both `feature_space` and `document` are lists.

- `document` is a list of words (a word may exist more than once!)
- `feature_space` is a list of labels (features)

Comment: What is `document`? If not a set or dictionary, make it one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters see my edit. Thanks i did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, with a *dict comprehension*:

```
def get_features(document, feature_space):
    return {w: (w in document) for w in feature_space}
```

The `features[key] = value` expression becomes the `key: value` part at the start, and the rest of the `for` loop(s) and any `if` statements follow in nesting order.

Yes, this will give you a performance boost, because you've now removed all `features` local name lookups and the `dict.__setitem__` calls.

Note that you need to make sure that `document` is a data structure that has fast membership tests. If it is a list, convert it to a `set()` first, for example, to ensure that membership tests take O(1) (constant) time, not the O(n) linear time of a list:

```
def get_features(document, feature_space):
    document = set(document)
    return {w: (w in document) for w in feature_space}
```

With a `set`, this is now a O(K) loop instead of a O(KN) loop (where N is the size of `document`, `K` the size of  `feature_space)`.